# Good way to draw Console UIs in Cosmos?

Tags: cosmos

So I'm developing an OS using C# and Cosmos. It's called Memphis, and I want it to be entirely command-line for now (like DOS).

But, something that most command-line OSes I've seen (Arch, DOS, etc) all have something like a console library that lets you create simple UIs with buttons, menus, inputs, etc.

I've already tried to write my own, but it was completely futile. I can draw a window and text on-screen, but not much else (I did have a basic window manager that kind of worked but didn't, you press tab to switch between windows, and left/right to select inputs like buttons, textboxes, etc and it did accept keyboard input and I could see the windows updating, but nothing actually changed despite the code theoretically working)

So I'm looking for a way for me to draw UIs on the console for my OS, but it has to be ENTIRELY managed, and must ONLY use what's in System.Console. It also CANNOT contain events. This is because, Cosmos can only really work with code that's 100% managed, and System.Console is implemented almost fully in Cosmos, and events throw an 'OpCode Mkrefany not yet implemented' when Cosmos' IL2CPU assembler tries to convert the compiled c# code to x86 ASM.

Comment: `So I'm looking for a library`  This is off-topic for StackOverflow.  Read [What Can I ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Edited. I guess I've got the balls to write my own code, just need a way to approach this properly.